# Mass object Expiring Strategy architecture

Tags: database, architecture

Lets say I have table in my database with few million objects. Each object has property `dateCreated`.
By default all object should expire 48 hours from the time they were created.

#### What would be the best strategy of checking when objects are expiring.

Preferred precision would be seconds but in sake of performance minutes are an option too.

Comment: Do you have to purge the objects as soon as they expire or is it possible to run a scheduled clean-up job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have some sort of component that was always running (like a background service).

Have this regularly pull references to the objects due to expire within a given time-frame - keeping in mind that whilst an objects expiry might be in seconds / minutes, you can pull the data less regularly than that (say every 5 mins, 20 mins, hour).  This will depend on the minimum amount of time an object can live for (the time between creation and expiry).

At the moment it sounds like 48 hours so you could arguably pull data in every 48 hours, but processing smaller amounts of data more regularly sounds better IMO.  Internally it would constantly be expiring objects - could be every second I guess, and if the expiry command is performed asynchronously you wouldn't need to worry (as much) about the previous batch completing before the next one kicks off.

This component would do nothing but pull the data and co-ordinate the expiry.
I'm assuming the actual act of expiry would be done elsewhere; so this component would either issue commands (too chatty?) or issue a batch command (not a "batch-job" just a list of objects to be expired now?).

The other approach is to say that the service is logically part of the main application even though it's physically separate (in an isolated service), that would allow it to perform the actual expiry.

Internally the expiry service could keep a working list in memory; when it "expires" an object make sure you perform that in a transaction, which would update some sort audit / log.  Should the service die you would then know what had been processed.

When the service comes back to live it would pick up the next range of objects - which would include ones not processed properly last time - these you could flag for special treatment, if necessary.

If you can't build a service you need to find something that runs as frequently as you need to delete objects.

Answer (score 1):

keep a list of the next object to expire in the time window you decide (minutes/seconds), update the list with the next objects to expire when it is empty and expire each object when it is its time.

Comment: @Ido - by "list" I assume you mean a collection of objects in memory in the application?

Comment: @Matt - If Ido means storing them in the app and using some sort of controller that would be a good approach.  When it starts up the controller would get anything that was old - regardless of how old, this would allow the system to be self-correcting after an unexpected shut-down.  You would also be to identify items that were past the target expiry window and flag them for special treatment, if necessary.

Comment: Sorry I disappeared. 
@Adrian - yes, this is more or less what I meant.
Mat - I think Adrian got a good solution in the full answer and I see you think so as well. Good luck with implementation.

Answer (score 1):

What about hourly or smaller (let's say 10 minute) **partitions ?** You could ditch whole partition(s) when removing data.